# Interpreting iterative smoothers and solvers as krylov preconditioners

Tags: linear-algebra, preconditioning

Various literature and library implementations like petsc use preconditioners based on simple smoothers that themselves could be used the solve the systems directly. e.g. say I have a function

```
void do_jacobi_smooth(const matrix A, vector x, const vector b);
```

which updates $x$ for the system $Ax=b$. Say I have a system where repeated calls to this eventually converge.

What I'm confused by in the literature of preconditioned methods, is that e.g. from the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method for conjugate gradient you see the use of a preconditioner $M^{-1}$ written as

$$
z_0 := M^{-1}r_0
$$

so that $M^{-1}$ is some kind of (here linear) operator.

My question is what is the form of this operator, as implemented by something like the `do_jacobi_smooth(A,x,b)` above? In other words, say I have an unpreconditioned conjugate gradient implementation, and a jacobi smoother implementation (or a multigrid solver), how do I connect these parts to get a preconditioned CG?

Is it as simple as applying one iteration with a 0 initial guess?